# Alt flux action: _this.actions is undefined even when this.generateActions is called

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, reactjs-flux

I am using the [Alt](http://alt.js.org/) library in my React/Flux project to represent the Flux part and I got to actions creators.

I created the following action:

```
// alt.js
import Alt from 'alt';

export default new Alt();

// UserActions.js
import alt from '../alt';

class UserActions {
    constructor() {
        this.generateActions(
            'getUsersSuccess',
            'getUsersFailed'
        );
    }

    getUsers(userId) {
        $.ajax({ url: '/api/users/'+userId })
        .done((data) => {
            this.actions.getUsersSuccess(data);
        })
        .fail((jqXhr) => {
            this.actions.getUsersFailed(jqXhr);
        });
    }
}

export default alt.createActions(UserActions);
```

The problem is the actions, `this.actions`, are undefined. Do I understand it correctly, that the `this.generateActions` function should populate the `actions` property of the `UserActions` class, or do I need to write something else in order to have the actions available?

I believe, using ES6, the `this` inside the anonymous functions should be correctly tied to `this` of the `UserActions` class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if the implementation of Alt has changed recently, but I had to manually code the actions with dispatch, in order to get it working, and call these functions directly instead of trying to access them using the `actions` property.

This is the code I have got, which can successfuly be loaded to store and maps the actions the way they should be mapped.

```
import alt from '../alt';

class UserActions{
    getUsers(userId) {
        $.ajax({url: 'api/users/'+userId})
            .done((data) => {
                this.getUsersSuccess(data);
            })
            .fail((jqHxr) => {
                this.getUsersFail(jqHxr);
            });
        return false;
    }

    getUsersSuccess(data) {
        return (dispatch) => {
            dispatch(data);
        }
    }

    getUsersFail(jqHxr) {
        return (dispatch) => {
            dispatch(jqHxr);
        }
    }
}

export default alt.createActions(UserActions);
```

With this approach the `generateActions` call in constructor is not only unnecessary, but needs to be avoided, otherwise the store using this action creator will not know which action you want to use.

I also added the `return false` at the end of the `getUsers` function to supress console warning thrown by alt (false must be returned when a function does not dispatch).

The dispatched actions here, `getUsersSuccess` and `getUsersFail`, should then have counterparts in the store which consumes the parameter/parameters and affects state.

Comment: thanks for share your solution, i was having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary any more to use actions, try:

```
// alt.js
import Alt from 'alt';
export default new Alt();

// UserActions.js
import alt from '../alt';

class UserActions {
    constructor() {
        this.generateActions(
            'getUsersSuccess','getUsersFailed'
        );
    }

    getUsers(userId) {
        $.ajax({ url: '/api/users/'+userId })
        .done((data) => {
            this.getUsersSuccess(data);
        })
        .fail((jqXhr) => {
            this.getUsersFailed(jqXhr);
        });
    }
}
export default alt.createActions(UserActions);
```